# Flush cache storage magento

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2

I have installed and then uninstalled maintenance site extension for my site,
but now some ip addresses can't have access to my site, does flush cache storage may solve this (does with the flush my site will work like it should ?) Please help me with this.

Answer (score 1):

When you say other IP addresses cant access your magento site, is this reports from clients or yourself?

Please check the settings withing magento:
System -> Configuration -> At the bottom -> Store Maintenance
Have a look to see if there are IP restrictions there, also could be a possibility that other client needs to refresh their cache.

Comment: If he has uninstalled the extension the settings should be gone I guess? Or the uninstalling went wrong

Comment: absolutely, but as we have no idea how it was installed im just making guestamations on what can happen, but i think potential error could be session key related.

Comment: i have uninstalled the extension and now i don't have store maintenance ... the client also clear the browser cache,but it is the same with the maintenance page... i don't know  that the maintenance extension log some file on my site how to clear that..

Comment: HI Axl could you please provide a URL so we can view, have you cleared all caches? I am aware that there is a known instance where, if your sessions arent writeable it can go to server directories.

Comment: If you're using firefox use https://addons.mozilla.org/nl/firefox/addon/live-http-headers/ to see what redirect headers are sent. Chrome should have an extension like that as well

Comment: the site is www.kniga.com.mk, i flush only magento cache, but not cache storage am afraid :)

Comment: I can visit it without issues. Nice shop btw. Can you get a log of the headers sent from one of the PC's that's having issues?

Comment: i don't know how to get log of the headers from pc's..sorry

Comment: Thank you all for your help, the problem was the provider ...Best regards

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what kind of extension you've used but if this is only for a couple of users it might be the client side cache that has stored the redirect the maintenance extension gave.
Try and flush the client side cache (browser cache) and see if that fixes the issue.

Optionally you can always flush the Magento cache but again, since it's only for a few users and you say you've uninstalled the extension (removed it completely?) it doesn't sound like a server side issue

Comment: yes, we try to clear cache on browser but it doesn't help,